# Rescatar el texto de un input con Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, groovy

Buenas tardes comunidad,
Estoy intentando rescatar el texto del siguiente elemento:

```
<table class="GroupsTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="1">
        " texto no seleccionado"

        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="5" checked>
        " texto seleccionado"

        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="3">
        " texto no seleccionado"

        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="21" checked>
        " texto seleccionado"

        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="12">
        " texto no seleccionado"

        <br>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

El problema es que el texto en sí esta fuera del elemento y no puedo capturarlo

Intente de la siguiente manera:

```
String include = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table[@class='grid contractGroupsTable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/input[@checked])[1]")).getText()
```

Esto me devuelve un texto vació.

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia es bien recibida, muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Qué elemento? Has puesto un input que no tiene texto, luego texto y luego un salto de línea, pero has omitido precisamente el elemento que contiene a todo esto

Comment: Por favor, añade mas estructura del html para poder ayudarte mejor. Ese texto parece pertenecer al padre de ese input, entonces sin una estructura mas completa no puedo ayudarte mucho.

Comment: Deje la estructura completa.. pero si como mencione es que el texto que necesito rescatar esta fuera del elemento en cuestión... y ese es el problema.

Comment: Colocando más detalles, en esa tabla existen muchos elementos de tipo checkbox y necesito rescatar el texto de los que e sten checkeados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo intentaria obtener el texto desde el padre, desde el td. De la siguiente forma:

```
String include = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@name='chk' and @checked]/ancestor::td")).getText();
```

Probablemente tengas que hacerle un borrado de espacios y saltos de linea.

```
include = include.trim();
```

Si quieres obtener todos tendras que utilizar la funcion `findElements`

Comment: Muchas gracias, me acabas de dar la pista que necesitaba para resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

primero que todo quiero agradecer a todos por sus respuestas

Me dieron las pistas que requería

La solución finalmente fue la siguiente:

```
def captureText(){
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    WebElement includeText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='grid contractGroupsTable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/input[@checked]/ancestor::td[1]"))
    List<String> includes = includeText.getText().split('\n')
    WebElement selectedInclude
    List<String> selectedIncludes = new ArrayList<>()
    for(int indexInclude = 1; indexInclude <= includes.size(); indexInclude++){
        selectedInclude = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='contract_groupids'])[" + indexInclude + "]"))
        if(selectedInclude.getAttribute("checked")){
            selectedIncludes.add(includes[indexInclude - 1])
        }
    }
}
```